# Working with a copy of my Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware-workstation

Hi there I'm trying to make a backup/copy of my virtual machine, it's installed in a Windows Server 2000 and I want to make some modifications/tests without changing the original one. The copy is to be used in Windows 7, what I'm trying to do is work/modify an application that communicates with a DB, this application is hosted on the VM, the DB too, and since I don't want to screw up the stable version I want to know how to copy the VM to my desktop pc to experiment without worries.

Now, someone told me I might have problems with the IP 'cause the original will have the same IP, and if I change it, it won't work properly. Is this true?

If it is indeed true, any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test modifications on the VM is probably by using either a "clone" or just by using "snapshots".  Clones appear as an independent new VM but actually make use of the original base VM, allow you to make changes, but all changes apply only to the clone, not to the base VM.  If you screw things up irreversibly you can always just delete the clone and create another.

Snapshots do not involve creating a new VM, but instead allow you to easily rollback the VM to its prior state if changes you make screw things up.

If you have problems understanding how clones and snapshots work after reading the documentation, or if you have to run a new VM using local files on a different machine, then you will want to make an actual copy.  It's a little more work but simpler conceptually so an actual copy is probably the way for you to go.

If you want to make an actual copy this involves just copying the main files for the VM, which generally for VMWare would be the vmdk files, for VirtualBox the vdi's, etc.  If you're not sure what you're doing then make copies from within the VM's interface.  Once done, all you need to do is copy the file(s) for the VM to a new location and open them from there.  I would suggest reading the appropriate documentation for your virtualizing software (e.g., VMWare, Virtualbox) and/or viewing tutorials or other info on the web like this one:  http://www.kernelhardware.org/how-to-move-virtualbox-guest-vm/

If the application and database are both running within the same VM, it's very likely that the connection is made via the "loopback" address of "localhost" or 127.0.0.1.  In this case there should be no configuration problem with the app and the db after moving them elsewhere on the network, since the application is already configured to always connect to the db running on the same VM as the application (regardless of what the VM's actual ip address is).

Answer (score 0):

I'd copy both the app and db and have win7 create a private network then you don't have to worry about dupe ip's.  Are these domain joined servers?  If so that will be an issue.